# How to create a quick Weather widget app using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-plugins, yahoo-weather-api, google-geolocation

I was wondering if there is an example of weather widget that can be created quickly and it would be better if it is lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to share some concepts of creating an application using **JavaScript**, **Jquery** and **Reactjs**. Which can help learning quickly than any other sources. Here is what I did using Reactjs:

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 310px;display: block;float: left; padding: 20px;">
   <div id="weather-app"></div>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-with-addons.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js'></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
       isLoading: true,
       toggleForm: false,
       isError: false
  }
},
 setError: function(value){
  this.setState({isError: value});
 },
 changeLoading: function(value){
   this.setState({isLoading: value});
 },
 onToggleForm: function(value){
   this.setState({toggleForm: value});
 },
onFormSubmit: function(c, s){
  this.onToggleForm(false);
  this.refs.change.toggleForm();
  this.refs.front.reRender(c, s);
  this.setState({isError: false});
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <div id="weather" className="weather">
      <ChangeBtn ref="change" isLoading={this.state.isLoading} toggleForm={this.onToggleForm} />
      <Front ref="front" isLoading={this.state.isLoading} isError={this.state.isError} setError={this.setError} loadCallback={this.changeLoading} toggle={this.state.toggleForm} />
      <Form isLoading={this.state.isLoading} toggle={this.state.toggleForm} onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} isError={this.state.isError} setError={this.setError} />
      <Spinner isLoading={this.state.isLoading} />
    </div>
  )
 }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("weather-app"));
```

1) Above code is **preview** only. Full Example can be found at this [**plnkr1**](https://plnkr.co/edit/leJouY1XRfO25OgMOY7F?p=preview) link.

2) I created same example using **Jquery** here:  [**plnkr2**](https://plnkr.co/edit/tPtp3Ot1pDIGlsD0ocmz?p=preview)

3) I wondered, what if I build the same using native JavaScript for extremely lightweight application? Then I also created the same using **pure JavaScript** here: [**plnkr3**](https://plnkr.co/edit/AMWsMQ3pUIC6Jiw8XoJa?p=preview)